# Row-reverse flexboxes not aligning well on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, alignment

I changed the format of an About Us section that works now on all browsers.  However, I tried fitting the flexboxes to mobile and only the even rows are not aligning correctly.  The odd rows align with the image followed by the text.  The even rows are still side-by-side with the text.  I tried changing the flex-direction to column, but it won't work.  What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css>
<link href=https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700,900|Ubuntu:400,500,700 rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px){ /*Desktop*/
.container {
    padding: 2px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container:nth-of-type(even) {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 2px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
img {
    width: 80%;
    
}
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px){ /*Desktop*/
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
h4 {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
}


.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 25px;
  
}

.container:nth-of-type(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #5e5c5c;
    text-align: center;

}
h4 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #5e5c5c;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
li {
    margin: 10px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

                                <!-----#Michael----->
<div class="container">
            <img src=https://i.postimg.cc/9QsRxd2q/Michael.png alt="Michael"/ width="25%" height="25%">
    <ul>
    <h1><b>Michael Schlaefer, CEO</b></h1>
    <h4><li>Owner of Global Development Contractors, LLC; Plymouth Industries, LLC; Liberty Stone & Aggregates - Clinton Quarry, LLC; Vision Development Group, LLC; and Green Earth Container Service, LLC.</li>
                <li>Over 40 years of experience in site work; demolition; remediation; trucking material management, facility operations, complex brownfield and landfill redevelopment projects.</li>
                <li>Board member – Tewksbury Environmental Commission</li></h4>
    </ul>
</div>

                                <!-----#Jen----->
<div class='container'>
  <img src=https://i.postimg.cc/nhX9YdyJ/Jen.png alt="Jen"/ width="25%" height="25%">
    <ul>
    <h1><b>Jennifer D. Kraft, COO</b></h1>
    <h4><li>In-house counsel for Global Development Contractors, LLC with extensive experience with material management, operations, site development and compliance with environment regulations.</li>
                <li>Chair – Tewksbury Board of Health</li>
                <li>Member – Professional Women in Construction (PWC)</li></h4>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than starting from a desktop browser and trying to modify things to work on a mobile device, it’s easier to start the other way around.

It’s also helpful to run your code through the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) as a way to check your code. Some of the standard things that your page didn’t have are:

- Your hrefs to Font Awesome and Google Fonts were lacking quotation marks.
- Image widths and heights, in the img tag, should be specified using pixels, not percentages (you can apply a percentage using a style).
- `h1` and `h4` tags aren’t supposed to be children of a `ul` tag.
- `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` have been [depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width). It’s best to use `max-width.`
- I added the required meta tags to the start of the head section.
- And it’s good to have the `lang` attribute on your `html` tag.

I moved your h1 tag and your list into separate `divs` so that they’ll stay together, and I put the switching point to go from in-a-row to vertical at 768 pixels (tablet size). You can change the value to whatever works for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700,900%7CUbuntu:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">


    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .wrapper {
            max-width: 960px;
            margin: 2rem auto;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 25px;

        }

        .container:nth-of-type(even) {
            flex-direction: row-reverse;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;

        }

        .img-about {
            max-width: 33%;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 26px;
            color: #5e5c5c;
            text-align: center;

        }

        .experience {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #5e5c5c;
            line-height: 1.25;
        }

        li {
            margin: 10px;

        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {

            /*Desktop*/
            .container {
                padding: 2px;
                height: auto;
                width: auto;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .container:nth-of-type(even) {
                flex-direction: column;
                padding: 2px;
                height: auto;
                width: auto;
            }

            .img-about {
                width: 33%;
            }

            /*Desktop*/
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            h4 {
                text-align: left;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- #Michael -->
        <div class="container">
            <img class="img-about" src=https://i.postimg.cc/9QsRxd2q/Michael.png alt="Michael">
            <div>
                <h1><strong>Michael Schlaefer, CEO</strong></h1>
                <ul class="experience">
                    <li>Owner of Global Development Contractors, LLC; Plymouth Industries, LLC; Liberty Stone & Aggregates - Clinton Quarry, LLC; Vision Development Group, LLC; and Green Earth Container Service, LLC.</li>
                    <li>Over 40 years of experience in site work; demolition; remediation; trucking material management, facility operations, complex brownfield and landfill redevelopment projects.</li>
                    <li>Board member – Tewksbury Environmental Commission</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--#Jen -->
        <div class='container'>
            <img class="img-about" src=https://i.postimg.cc/nhX9YdyJ/Jen.png alt="Jen">
            <div>
                <h1><strong>Jennifer D. Kraft, COO</strong></h1>
                <ul class="experience">
                    <li>In-house counsel for Global Development Contractors, LLC with extensive experience with material management, operations, site development and compliance with environment regulations.</li>
                    <li>Chair – Tewksbury Board of Health</li>
                    <li>Member – Professional Women in Construction (PWC)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! This format is definitely cleaner and easier to work with.